# SQL query with subquery takes longer than both queries separately

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, query-optimization

### Problem

I have two queries where one needs the result of the other one. My first guess was to use an independent subquery:

```sql
SELECT P2.*
FROM ExampleTable P2
WHERE P2.delivery_start >= (
    SELECT MIN(P1.delivery_start)
    FROM ExampleTable P1
    WHERE 1641288602 < P1.delivery_end
);
```

The entire query takes 5-6 seconds which is way to long for my application. Running these queries after another takes only around 800ms for both:

```sql
SELECT MIN(P1.delivery_start)
FROM ExampleTable P1
WHERE 1641288602 < P1.delivery_end;
```

```sql
SELECT P2.*
FROM ExampleTable P2
WHERE P2.delivery_start >= 1641286800;
```

I am using Mariadb 10.2 and have indices on both `delivery_start` and `delivery_end`.

### What I have tried

I have used a CTE instead of a subquery which resulted in the same performance. Using a Variable with `SET` yields similar results as to running both queries separately, so thats what I will use for the time being.

I ran `EXPLAIN` on all 3 Queries:

##### 1. Query with subquery

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | P2 | ALL | delivery_start | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6388282 | Using where |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | P1 | range | delivery_end | delivery_end | 4 | NULL | 36378 | Using index condition |

##### 2. Separate Queries

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | P1 | range | delivery_end | delivery_end | 4 | NULL | 36432 | Using index condition |

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | P2 | range | delivery_start | delivery_start | 4 | NULL | 35944 | Using index condition |

### Question

I think the issue is shown in the first `EXPLAIN` table as it has type `ALL` which means that the database performs a full table scan. My question is simply: why? Is the optimizer not able to figure out that the subquery produces a number with which we only need a `range` type query? And why does it not use any index?

Comment: How many rows does the predicate `1641288602 < P1.delivery_end`of the subquery selects  (average percent) ?

Comment: You are using inequalities in the search criteria, and this leads to portentially massive data reads. I would assume this is a non-interactive process, so 5 seconds should be pretty good. Now, if you want to process such amount of data interactively, then you have a design problem.

Comment: @TheImpaler The table holds like 6 million entries, but I think it should not be relevant as running both queries after another (even non-interactively with a `SET` Variable) runs much faster than 5s.

Comment: @BobMcFry There's a architectural problem here. The query can be suitable for a non-interactive use, but it seems you want to use it interactively. If that's the case you'll need to perform preprocessing (or use redundancy) to reduce the number of ineractive reads substantially.

Comment: @TheImpaler I do not want to use it interactively. I just want to know why the performance is that much worse as opposed to doing 2 queries which I am doing right know in my program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is described in the MariaDB docs:

> In all remaining cases when NULL cannot be substituted with FALSE, it
> is not possible to use index lookups. This is not a limitation in the
> server, but a consequence of the NULL semantics in the ANSI SQL
> standard.

There is a full examination here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/non-semi-join-subquery-optimizations/

The result of your *subquery* can potentially return a NULL in the case no rows were found. Hence, MariaDB cannot use the index for the parent query.

You must rewrite your subquery in a way that it will always return a row with a non-NULL scalar or stick with two separate queries. However, what should happen if your first query returns NULL? With a compound statement you could put an if around the second query and don't even execute it if the first returns NULL.

Comment: Could you add a link to this assertion please.

Comment: I've added the link.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these

```
INDEX(delivery_start)
INDEX(delivery_end)
```

with these:

```
INDEX(delivery_start, delivery_end)
INDEX(delivery_end, delivery_start)
```

The second one will help significantly with the subquery.  Then the first may help with the outer query.

(If those don't help, please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and table sizes.)